# font awesome icon displayed as a square

Tags: html, css, laravel, font-awesome

I wanna make an icon for my sidebar using font awesome, but the icon turns to a square.
I can use cdn, but i wanna try offline. I put my all.min.css in css folder in public folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he9Ci.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2vzq.png)
I've tried many tutorial but it doesn't work

Comment: please add your HTML and CSS as text and **not** simply as an image of your code

Answer (score 2):

When icon does not render, it's because it's missing from library. So make sure that you're calling the right icon name. Font awesome icons normally have a format like this: 'fa fa-icon-name' so try to search '.fa-icon-name' inside font awesome css library to check if it exists.

This problem is caused by using a library that it's not updated, or by using paid icons with free library.

Comment: Ah i see. Thank you for your solution